# Recursion in char_charset?

Tags: characters

I am looking at the C code for Emacs as of Emacs 26.1, file `charset.c` , defun `char-charset` (around line 2040), and file `charset.h`, macro `CHAR_CHARSET` (around line 380). I don't understand how in the world this might work. How does this not recurse without bound if `ch >= 0x80` and `restriction == Qnil` ??

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. `CHAR_CHARSET` is a macro and it either expands to the `CHARSET_FROM_ID` macro or the `char_charset` function. Which isn't the same as the macro and doesn't use recursion either, just expansions of `CHARSET_FROM_ID`.

Comment: @wasamasa: the macro calls back the *function* `char_charset`, which calls the macro, which calls the function , ...

Comment: @Drew: are you sure the `debugging` tag applies? I am not saying this is a bug, and when I execute the function with `S-M-:` it does not in fact loop. I am just looking at the code trying to undestand how it can possibly work.

Comment: Perhaps if there were a "code archeology" tag, that would fit better than "debugging"

Comment: I've removed it. I added it in the sense that you wanted to find out what was going on. But I agree that's not really about debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't recursive, because there are actually three bits of code in play. First there is the Lisp function `char-charset`, then there is the CHAR_CHARSET macro, and finally there is the C function `char_charset`. All three are distinct. The Lisp function `char-charset` is also given the name Fchar_charset inside the Emacs binary's symbol table, although there are no calls to it by that name. (The metadata used by the Lisp interpreter when it examines this function is stored in the static global variable Schar_charset.)

It doesn't recurse because the macro calls the function `char_charset`, not `Fchar_charset`. But certainly the Hamming distance between these names is not very great, so it is an easy mistake to make.